# Content width + some amount of px with calc()

Tags: css, sass, width

I know i can do `calc(100% + 15px)`, but is there way to do 
calc("content width" + 15px)?

fit-content and auto didn't work, which kinda makes sense.

I have unknown number of items that i want just to take width they need (inline-block) + some amount of px for `justify-content: space-between;`

If this can't be done with calc, is there an alternative?

(I'm using scss if that changes anything)

Comment: If they are inline block can't you just add padding?

Comment: Can you share your use case, I am pretty sure there is an easy way to what you want

Comment: Yeah, how about using a CS table and `border-spacing`. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/s91254cg/3/

Comment: Yeah, i totally overlooked `:not(:last-child)` selector and padding-right and narrowed it to usage of calc() and flexbox. Your comment shifted me to the right direction.

But i still wonder if it is possible to do such thing with calc(), without js and accessing the dom.

Comment: Good question. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

Use padding.  The content+padding => determines size without using % percentage for width.

In my scenario, a button added a '>' using pseudo ::after, and was positioned 18px from the right edige.

Comment: Any code sample ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try the following ?

`width: max-content;`

It works on my case. I have a `<div>` whose children somehow wrapped. Somehow `fit-content` nor `auto` did not work. But  `width: max-content;` works.

Answer (score 0):

I also found myself in this situation, unfortunately not having found a solution I used a small JS function that assigns the value

```
width: calc ($(element).width() + 10px);
```

Unfortunately, rather than calculating the measure via javascript when loading the page I can not help you.